# upgrade to laravel 5.3 -- issues with Route::prefix

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, upgrade

upgraded from 5.1 to 5.3, followed all the instructions...
https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade#upgrade-5.3.0

Now I am getting

```
BadMethodCallException in Macroable.php line 74:
Method prefix does not exist.
in Macroable.php line 74
at Router->__call('prefix', array('api')) in Facade.php line 237
at Facade::__callStatic('prefix', array('api')) in RouteServiceProvider.php line 58
at RouteServiceProvider->mapApiRoutes() in RouteServiceProvider.php line 32
at RouteServiceProvider->map()
at call_user_func_array(array(object(RouteServiceProvider), 'map'), array()) in Container.php line 508
at Container->call(array(object(RouteServiceProvider), 'map')) in RouteServiceProvider.php line 69
at RouteServiceProvider->loadRoutes() in RouteServiceProvider.php line 30
at RouteServiceProvider->boot() in RouteServiceProvider.php line 23
at RouteServiceProvider->boot()
at call_user_func_array(array(object(RouteServiceProvider), 'boot'), array()) in Container.php line 508
at Container->call(array(object(RouteServiceProvider), 'boot')) in Application.php line 769
at Application->bootProvider(object(RouteServiceProvider)) in Application.php line 752
at Application->Illuminate\Foundation\{closure}(object(RouteServiceProvider), '16')
at array_walk(array(object(EventServiceProvider), object(RoutingServiceProvider), object(AuthServiceProvider), object(CookieServiceProvider), object(DatabaseServiceProvider), object(EncryptionServiceProvider), object(FilesystemServiceProvider), object(FoundationServiceProvider), object(PaginationServiceProvider), object(SessionServiceProvider), object(ViewServiceProvider), object(NotificationServiceProvider), object(AppServiceProvider), object(AuthServiceProvider), object(ConfigServiceProvider), object(EventServiceProvider), object(RouteServiceProvider), object(DatabaseServiceProvider), object(BraintreeServiceProvider), object(BroadcastServiceProvider), object(FlashServiceProvider), object(ExcelServiceProvider), object(CashierServiceProvider), object(EntrustServiceProvider), object(AnalyticsServiceProvider), object(JWTAuthServiceProvider), object(ApidocsServiceProvider), object(ServiceProvider), object(GeoIPServiceProvider), object(PdfServiceProvider), object(LaravelPhoneServiceProvider)), object(Closure)) in Application.php line 753
at Application->boot() in BootProviders.php line 17
at BootProviders->bootstrap(object(Application)) in Application.php line 203
at Application->bootstrapWith(array('Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\DetectEnvironment', 'Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\LoadConfiguration', 'Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\ConfigureLogging', 'Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions', 'Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\RegisterFacades', 'Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\RegisterProviders', 'Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\BootProviders')) in Kernel.php line 254
at Kernel->bootstrap() in Kernel.php line 145
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 117
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 52
```

- ran composer dump-autoload
- ran composer update (just to get the latest and greatest)
- what else can i do?

The code for RouteServiceProvider is exact copy from laravel.

not sure why it is not loading! the method is not recognized, but i can see it in the Router class.

**composer.json**

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"require": {
    "laravel/framework": "5.3.*",
    "laravelcollective/html": "~5.0",
    "laracasts/flash": "~1.3",
    "maatwebsite/excel": "~2.1",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~6.2",
    "doctrine/dbal": "~2.5",
    "laravel/cashier": "~7.0",
    "league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3": "~1.0",
    "zizaco/entrust": "1.7.0",
    "barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper": "^2.2",
    "blueimp/jquery-file-upload": "^9.14",
    "ipunkt/laravel-analytics": "^1.3",
    "braintree/braintree_php": "^3.21",
    "tymon/jwt-auth": "0.5.*",
    "f2m2/apidocs": "~2.0",
    "barryvdh/laravel-cors": "0.8.*",
    "pulkitjalan/geoip": "~2.4",
    "aws/aws-sdk-php-laravel": "^3.1",
    "vsmoraes/laravel-pdf": "^1.0",
    "propaganistas/laravel-phone": "^2.8",
    "activecampaign/api-php": "~2.0"
},
"require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
    "phpspec/phpspec": "~2.1",
    "ozankurt/repoist": "^1.0",
    "symfony/dom-crawler": "~3.1",
    "symfony/css-selector": "~3.1"
},
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "APP\\": "app/"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "classmap": [
        "tests/TestCase.php"
    ]
},
"scripts": {
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "php artisan key:generate"
    ],
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist"
}
```

}

**RouteServiceProvider**

```
<?php
namespace App\Providers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\RouteServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;
class RouteServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * This namespace is applied to your controller routes.
     *
     * In addition, it is set as the URL generator's root namespace.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';
    /**
     * Define your route model bindings, pattern filters, etc.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //
        parent::boot();
    }
    /**
     * Define the routes for the application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function map()
    {
        $this->mapApiRoutes();
        $this->mapWebRoutes();
        //
    }
    /**
     * Define the "web" routes for the application.
     *
     * These routes all receive session state, CSRF protection, etc.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function mapWebRoutes()
    {
        Route::middleware('web')
            ->namespace($this->namespace)
            ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
    }
    /**
     * Define the "api" routes for the application.
     *
     * These routes are typically stateless.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function mapApiRoutes()
    {
        Route::prefix('api')
            ->middleware('api')
            ->namespace($this->namespace)
            ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));
    }
}
```

**another test**
i swapped the prefix and middleware calls and got this error...

*SWAPPED ORDER*

```
protected function mapApiRoutes()
{
    Route::middleware('api')->prefix('api')
        ->namespace($this->namespace)
        ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));
}
```

*ERROR*

```
FatalThrowableError in Router.php line 859:
Type error: Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Routing\Router::middleware(), 1 passed in /var/www/vhosts/camp-native/API-v.2-master/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php on line 237 and exactly 2 expected
in Router.php line 859
at Router->middleware('api') in Facade.php line 237
at Facade::__callStatic('middleware', array('api')) in RouteServiceProvider.php line 58
at RouteServiceProvider->mapApiRoutes() in RouteServiceProvider.php line 32
at RouteServiceProvider->map()
at call_user_func_array(array(object(RouteServiceProvider), 'map'), array()) in Container.php line 508
at Container->call(array(object(RouteServiceProvider), 'map')) in RouteServiceProvider.php line 69
at RouteServiceProvider->loadRoutes() in RouteServiceProvider.php line 30
at RouteServiceProvider->boot() in RouteServiceProvider.php line 23
at RouteServiceProvider->boot()
at call_user_func_array(array(object(RouteServiceProvider), 'boot'), array()) in Container.php line 508
at Container->call(array(object(RouteServiceProvider), 'boot')) in Application.php line 769
at Application->bootProvider(object(RouteServiceProvider)) in Application.php line 752
at Application->Illuminate\Foundation\{closure}(object(RouteServiceProvider), '16')
at array_walk(array(object(EventServiceProvider), object(RoutingServiceProvider), object(AuthServiceProvider), object(CookieServiceProvider), object(DatabaseServiceProvider), object(EncryptionServiceProvider), object(FilesystemServiceProvider), object(FoundationServiceProvider), object(PaginationServiceProvider), object(SessionServiceProvider), object(ViewServiceProvider), object(NotificationServiceProvider), object(AppServiceProvider), object(AuthServiceProvider), object(ConfigServiceProvider), object(EventServiceProvider), object(RouteServiceProvider), object(DatabaseServiceProvider), object(BraintreeServiceProvider), object(BroadcastServiceProvider), object(FlashServiceProvider), object(ExcelServiceProvider), object(CashierServiceProvider), object(EntrustServiceProvider), object(AnalyticsServiceProvider), object(JWTAuthServiceProvider), object(ApidocsServiceProvider), object(ServiceProvider), object(GeoIPServiceProvider), object(PdfServiceProvider), object(LaravelPhoneServiceProvider)), object(Closure)) in Application.php line 753
at Application->boot() in BootProviders.php line 17
at BootProviders->bootstrap(object(Application)) in Application.php line 203
at Application->bootstrapWith(array('Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\DetectEnvironment', 'Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\LoadConfiguration', 'Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\ConfigureLogging', 'Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions', 'Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\RegisterFacades', 'Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\RegisterProviders', 'Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\BootProviders')) in Kernel.php line 254
at Kernel->bootstrap() in Kernel.php line 145
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 117
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 52
```

Comment: Me too facing the exact same issue at the moment, I upgraded from 5.1 to 5.2 it worked just fine with very little patches , then i had to upgrade it to 5.3 after which there are some issues and this seems to be the first. Any luck for you??

Answer (score 2):

That link is the upgrade from 5.2 to 5.3, so you might also need to check the 5.1 to 5.2 one as well.

Looks like it might be the API routes and middleware that are missing. On that update link you have look up the API and the section with ref to:

```
'api' => [
    'throttle:60,1',
     'bindings',
 ],
```

and within the `app/Providors/RouteServiceProvider` your looking for somethign like:

```
   protected function mapApiRoutes()
      {
          Route::prefix('api')
             ->middleware('api')
             ->namespace($this->namespace)
             ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));
   }
```

Hope this helps and might be a clue?

Comment: the link is to all the upgrades, just have to scroll down further ;)

Comment: i followed all of the instructions and the api routes are defined as detailed. Any other ideas?

Comment: gather the the App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class,
 is in the config/app.php providors list? also can you add the whole of the RouteServiceProvider within your question so we can check against a fresh install, as that's how i sometimes check etc

Answer (score 1):

I was recently stuck with the same issue, While I was trying to upgrade my application from `5.2` to `5.3`.

After so much hair pulling and error solving I realized, that there was a fault in my `RouteServiceProvider.php` file. Here is how I solved my problem.

I replaced:

```
Route::prefix('api')
    ->middleware('api')
    ->namespace($this->namespace)
    ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));
```

with

```
Route::group([
    'middleware' => 'api',
    'namespace' => $this->namespace,
    'prefix' => 'api'
    ], function($router){
        require base_path('routes/api.php');
    });
```

It worked wonder for me. Now, I don't have any middleware related errors.

**BTW:** You need to do the same thing with `mapWebRoutes` function if you error is related to `web`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! I think I also had to rewrite my routes/api.php file to use Route::group() insead of Route::middleware()